# Django not recognizing app_label meta data

Tags: python, sql-server, django

**Problem**

I have multiple DBs to connect to for different apps on my Django server, which only serves datas from the DB. I recently added new DB and ran `python3 manage.py inspectdb --database=new_db`, then I added `app_label` for the correct DB connection. But somehow Django is keep returning programming errors with invalid object name errors. I double-checked, and DB and tables are exactly there. Then I found out that the model was trying to connect to its default database, which doesn't have a table I am trying to connect to. What should I try to fix this?

**Summaries**

1. Django model is trying to connect to its default DB, in spite it has explicitly declared target DB on its Meta part.
2. DB declaration seems to be fine because `inspectdb` was done perfectly.
3. There's no typo on DB declaration, too.

**<DB declaration on 'settings.py'>**

```
DATABASES = {
  'default' : {
    'ENGINE' : 'mssql',
    'NAME' : 'DEFAULT_DB',
    'USER' : env('DB_USER'),
    'PASSWORD' : env('DB_PASSWORD'),
    'HOST' : env('DB_HOST'),
    'PORT' : env('DB_PORT'), 
  },
  'new_db' : {
    'ENGINE' : 'mssql',
    'NAME' : 'NEW_DB',
    'USER' : env('DB_USER'),
    'PASSWORD' : env('DB_PASSWORD'),
    'HOST' : env('DB_HOST'),
    'PORT' : env('DB_PORT'), 
  }
}
```

**<Meta data of 'models.py'>**

```
  class Meta:
    managed = False
    app_label='new_db'
    db_table='NEW_TB'
```

Comment: "_explicitly declared target DB on its Meta part._" As far as I am aware there is no such meta option to specify the database to be used for a model? `db_table` is just used to control the tables name in the database. Controlling which model goes to which database is done by using [database routers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/multi-db/#automatic-database-routing) which I don't see you using?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Thanks, dbrouter.py was what I was missing. I was supposed to modify it first and then use app_label to designate target DB, but I only designated the target DB. So there was no such DB data like 'new_db' in my django. Now it's working.